# Random number game help - issue with if statement

Tags: java

I am currently completing my first java course and assignment based on a random number game.
I am having some issues with some if greater and less statements.

I would really appreciate some general comments.

The reason I am looking to input the 'random' number is for testing purposes
I also need to incorporate `get()` and `set()` methods as the assignment entails object oriented programming so I need to use multiple classes

Any advice would be highly appreciated

**The problem I'm having is that the last if statement which checks random number is in range is always getting the output that it is out of range regardless**

---

```
 package randomnumbergame;

 /*
  * @author Matthew O
  */

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args)
{


int numGuesses = 3;
int rangeMin = 1;
int rangeMax = 10;
int randomNum = 0;

Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);


System.out.println("Welcome to the random number game!");
System.out.println("The object of this game is to correctly "
+"guess a number between a set range within a certain ammount of guesses.");
System.out.println("\nThe default range is " + rangeMin + " - " + rangeMax); 
System.out.println("Would you like to change this?");                          
System.out.println("Please enter y for yes or n for no and press enter.");

String range = scan.nextLine();           
char changeRange = range.charAt(0);    
if (! (changeRange == 'Y' || changeRange == 'y'|| changeRange == 'n' || changeRange == 'N'))  
    {
    System.out.println("Error: invalid input entered for the interstate question");   
    System.exit(0);                                                          
    }                                                                           

if (changeRange == 'Y' || changeRange == 'y')       
    {
    System.out.println ("\nPlease enter the new numerical minimum value for the range");      
    int newRangeMin = scan.nextInt();                                              
    rangeMin = newRangeMin;                                  
    System.out.println ("\nPlease enter the new maximum numerical value for the range");       
    int newRangeMax = scan.nextInt();                                               
    rangeMax = newRangeMax;         
    }

{
System.out.println("\nThe default number of guesses is " + numGuesses);         
System.out.println("Would you like to change this?");                           
System.out.println("\nPlease enter y for yes or n for no and press enter.");    

String guesses = scan.next();                                                  
char changeGuesses = guesses.charAt(0);                                         
if (! (changeGuesses == 'Y' || changeGuesses == 'y' || changeGuesses == 'n' || changeGuesses 
== 'N'))                           

    {
System.out.println("Error: invalid input entered for the interstate question");           
System.exit(0);
    }

if (changeGuesses == 'Y' || changeGuesses == 'y')
    {
System.out.println("\nPlease enter the new number of permitted guesses");       
int newGuesses = scan.nextInt();                                               
numGuesses = newGuesses;                                                       
    }

    {
System.out.println ("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");                                     
System.out.println("Welcome to the random number game!\n");                     
System.out.println("You have chosen a range of " + rangeMin + " to " + rangeMax);
System.out.println("You have chosen to have " + numGuesses + " Guesses");       
    }
}

{
System.out.println("\nPlease press y to input the random number or n" + 
" to let the number be automatically generated");           
String random = scan.next();                                                    
char changeRandom = random.charAt(0);                                          
if (! (changeRandom == 'Y' || changeRandom == 'y' || changeRandom == 'n' || 
changeRandom == 'N'))                            
    {
    System.out.println("Error: invalid input entered for the interstate question");     
    System.exit(0);
    }

   if (changeRandom == 'Y' || changeRandom == 'y')  
    {
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter the new 'random' number between "
    + rangeMin + " and " + rangeMax);                           
    int inputRandom = scan.nextInt();                                     
    randomNum = inputRandom;                                             
    System.out.println("\nThe 'random' number chosen for the game is " + randomNum);          
    }

if (randomNum < rangeMin);    
    {
    System.out.println("Random number is out of range!");     
    }

    }


 }

}
```

Comment: Indent your code properly: it's unreadable. And tell us *which* issues you're having, and with *which* statements.

Comment: Could you narrow your code down to the part that you are having a problem with? Also, please tell us what the problem is. "I am having some issues" is not a very helpful description of your problem.

Comment: sorry i realized this after i had posted. my issue is with my final if statement, to check if chosen number is in range, apparently it is always out of range

Comment: Could you tell us what the values of `randomNum` and `rangeMin` are at that point?

Comment: It will always execute the code inside the if statement, try removing the semicolon after that final if.

Comment: I autoindented your code as best as I could. Also, why do you have code between `{` and `}` that's not part of an `if`?

Comment: If you let us know which IDE you are using, we could instruct you on how to debug the code and find out why the values of your variables are different from what you'd expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an unnecessary `;` at the end of the `if` statement in question, so even if it is evaluated, the result is nothing.

```
if (randomNum < rangeMin); 
            {
                System.out.println("Random number is out of range!");           
            }
```

No matter how the `if` is evaluated, the message will always be printed.

Change the above to:

```
 if (randomNum < rangeMin)
                {
                    System.out.println("Random number is out of range!");           
                }
```

Comment: Thank you all so much for the speedy replies, it was an amateur mistake of me. And also very sorry for making your eyes bleed, i will work much harder on my indentation. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
if (randomNum < rangeMin);
{
    System.out.println("Random number is out of range!");
}
```

The problem is in the `;` (semicolon) on the first line. Java thinks it is the end of that `if` condition and prints your error message every time. The statement then says:

"If (randomNum < rangeMin), do nothing. Then print out *'Random number is out of range!'*."

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `;` symbol after if.

```
if (randomNum < rangeMin);
{
System.out.println("Random number is out of range!");
}
```